# Using measures on symmetric differences

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(X,M, µ)$ be a measure space, and let $A_j$ be a sequence in $M$ satisfying
$µ(A_j∆A_k) ≤ 1/2^j$ for all $1 ≤ j ≤ k$.
Show that $∃A ∈ M$ such that $µ(Aj∆A) → 0$ as $j → ∞$.

My attempt:

Let $A := lim inf_{j→∞} A_j := ∪_{n=1}^\inf ∩_{j=n}^\inf A_j$

Now, $A$ is an increasing sequence

$µ(Aj∆A_k) → 0$ as $j,k→ ∞$
With $A$ as defined above, it follows that $(Aj∆A)\subset (Aj∆A_k)$ for $j,k → ∞$

By subadditivity of measure, $µ(Aj∆A)\leq µ(Aj∆A_k)\leq 1/(2^j)$

For $j,k → ∞$, we can find $\epsilon$ such that $µ(Aj∆A_k)\leq \epsilon \implies µ(Aj∆A)\leq \epsilon \implies µ(Aj∆A) → 0$ as $j → ∞$

.
I am not sure if I have done it correctly. Please suggest.

Comment: A way to look at the whole thing that may be simpler: $\mu(A\Delta B)=||\chi_A-\chi_B||_1$.

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: Explain that formula, or explain why it helps? I'm not going to explain why $\mu(A\Delta B)=||\chi_A-\chi_B||_1$; you can simply work out what the norm is. Why it helps is that now your hypothesis shows that $(\chi_{A_j})$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^1$. So it converges to something in $L^1$. Since convergence in $L^1$ implies almost every convergence of a subsequence it follows that the limit is a characteristic function...

Comment: ok Thanks. I understand it.

Comment: But how about flaws in my proof?